# Inject input into process connected to standard input (interactive console)

Tags: php, command-line-interface, stdin

We have a tool which executes the PHP interactive shell like this:

```
$descriptorSpec = array(
    0 => STDIN,
    1 => STDOUT,
    2 => STDERR
);

$prependFile = __DIR__ . '/../../../../../res/dev/console_auto_prepend.php';
$exec = 'php -a -d auto_prepend_file=' . escapeshellarg($prependFile);

$pipes = array();
proc_open($exec, $descriptorSpec, $pipes);
```

The trick with `auto_prepend_file` unfortunately causes issues with autoloading on PHP 5.3. We found out that everyting works well when we include the file inside the interactive shell:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > include "myproject/res/dev/console_auto_prepend.php";
Autoloader initialized.
```

What we want to do is the following:

- execute php interactive shell via proc_open
- send the include line to the interactive shell
- hand over the controll to the user input

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Untested idea:

- Created a new input pipe
- Open the PHP process (`php -a`) with that input pipe, stdout and stderr could be connected to the system pipes
- Inject the include command (write to the input pipe)
- In a loop read from the STDIN and write to our new input pipe (which is connected to the `php -a`)

Answer (score -1):

The project ended up in using a custom PHP shell (`psysh`)